# Erro Pusher - Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Bom dia.

Segui a risca este tutorial: https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel

Porém recebo o seguinte erro no console do navegador:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined
at PusherConnector.connect (VM562 app.js:36739)
at PusherConnector.Connector (VM562 app.js:36305)
at new PusherConnector (VM562 app.js:36730)
at new Echo (VM562 app.js:36960)
at Object.VERSION (VM562 app.js:14124)
at __webpack_require__ (VM562 app.js:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (VM562 app.js:14005)
at __webpack_require__ (VM562 app.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (VM562 app.js:13990)
at __webpack_require__ (VM562 app.js:20)
```

Pesquisei e disseram que era para importar essa linha (import Pusher from "pusher-js") no bootstrap.js, porém o erro persiste.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Estou utilizando o laravel 5.6.37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, eu estava com um problema parecido e resolvi da seguinte forma:
Fiz a instalação do Pusher através deste tutorial: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-laravel
até a parte de "configuração".
Depois rodei um "npn run watch" no terminal.
Além disso, em resources/js/bootstrap.js
 atualize para:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: 'your-pusher-key'
});
```

Após isto minha aplicação de enviar mensagens funcionou.